# htaccess redirection from xyz.com/dynamicpage to xyz.com/page/dynamicpage

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, redirect

I have a website that have user profiles as their business names, like https://mywebsite.com/mybusinessname

What I am trying to achieve is to redirect this url to https://mywebsite.com/page/mybusinessname

businessname is dynamic, it can be reddevils, mycompany, westminster etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^((?!page/).*)$ /page/$1 [R=301,L,NC]
```

Comment: It makes all my css and images unable to load on the page, and it still gets me a 404 error

Comment: https://payppermint.com/reddevils, it again gets me a 404, the home page has wordpress installed and it has its own htaccess (its where i am putting the code you gave me), the target url are in code igniter which is set up in a folder named 'page' on the root.